# dynamic highcharts with json data every 1 second

Tags: python, highcharts

I have json_data like below

```js
[{"n":"0","y":"450","prediction_value":"449.191"},{"n":"1","y":"451.117","prediction_value":"451.259"},{"n":"2","y":"354.17","prediction_value":"354.352"},{"n":"3","y":"439.781","prediction_value":"439.939"},{"n":"4","y":"451.436","prediction_value":"451.611"},{"n":"5","y":"448.935","prediction_value":"448.991"},{"n":"6","y":"451.935","prediction_value":"451.806"},{"n":"7","y":"370.045","prediction_value":"369.802"},{"n":"8","y":"447.232","prediction_value":"447.231"},{"n":"9","y":"410.612","prediction_value":"410.873"},{"n":"10","y":"423.815","prediction_value":"423.923"},{"n":"11","y":"451.707","prediction_value":"451.867"},{"n":"12","y":"425.391","prediction_value":"425.287"},{"n":"13","y":"395.942","prediction_value":"395.905"},{"n":"14","y":"436.397","prediction_value":"436.682"},{"n":"15","y":"405.184","prediction_value":"405.027"},{"n":"16","y":"372.175","prediction_value":"372.128"}]
```

I want to draw 2 types of graph

- 1st graph have X=n, and Y=y, so y=f(n)
- 2nd graph have X=n, and Y=prediction_value, so prediction=f(n)

How can I draw two highcharts graph in same panel?

Answer (score 0):

For drawing two types of charts you can add two series for example.

```
  series: [{
      data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      type: 'column',
      data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3].reverse()
    }
  ]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4b6g9doy/

About loading data from json you can found here:
[preprocess-data-using-json](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#preprocess-data-using-json)

Dynamic load data: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/dynamic-update

But this example is JavaScript related, you need to find a way to port it to python.